# Change Dynamically Options then Select an Option

Tags: php, jquery

I'm now able to change the options dynamically using jQuery. The code below will change the breed options depending on the species selected:

```
<div class="pet-group">
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="species">
            <option value="1">Dog</option>
            <option value="2">Cat</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="breed">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).on("change", ".species", function(){
        var elem = $(this),
            speciesid = elem.val();
        $.get("http://localhost/Vet/get_breeds/"+speciesid, function( result ) {
            elem.closest('.form-group').find('.breed').html(result.breed_opts);
        }, "json" );
    });
</script>
```

---

But when a specific pet has been selected, I want the fields to be filled-in with data of the existing pet.

```
<div class="pet-group">
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="pet">
            <option value="1">Akamaru</option> <!-- e.g., Akamaru is a dog with Pug as the breed type -->
            <option value="2">Nina</option> <!-- e.g., Nina is a dog with Great Pyrenees as the breed type -->
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="species">
            <option value="1">Dog</option>
            <option value="2">Cat</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="breed">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(".pet").change(function(){
        var elem = $(this),
            petid = elem.val();

        $.get("http://localhost/Vet/get_pet_details/"+petid, function( result ) {
            elem.closest('.pet-group').find('.species').val(result.species_id).trigger('change');
            elem.closest('.pet-group').find('.breed').val(result.breed_id).trigger('change');
        });
    });
</script>
```

It does change the species field properly and dynamically loads the breed options but it doesn't select the right breed.

What should I so that the right breed will be selected?

Comment: `elem.closest('.pet-group').find('.breed').val(result.breed_id).trigger('change');` not needed inside `$(".pet").change(function(){` because there you already applied `.trigger('change');` of species. it will call ajax again to get breed data

Comment: @AlivetoDie - I still need it for my second event. For the first case, if the user will input a new pet, the user has to select a species, then it should populate the breed field. For the second case, if the user selects an existing pet, the species and the breed field should be filled-in based from the selected pet's data.

Answer (score 0):

When a specific pet has been selected, $.get("http://localhost/Vet/get_pet_details/"...) callback performs in this order:

Step 1: setting value of select.species:

```
elem.closest('.pet-group').find('.species').val(result.species_id)
```

Step 2: setting value of select.breed:

```
elem.closest('.pet-group').find('.breed').val(result.breed_id)
```

Step 3: call asynchronously event handler of select.species because of

```
elem.closest('.pet-group').find('.species').trigger("change");
```

Ajax gets new result.breed_opts, and fills the select.breed. Old value set in step 2 is erased.

So we can do this approach in your first script body:

```
<script>
    $(document).on("change", ".species", function(){
        var elem = $(this),
            speciesid = elem.val();
         $.get("http://localhost/Vet/get_breeds/"+speciesid, function( result ) {
             var objbreed = elem.closest('.pet-group').find('.breed');
             var oldbreedid = objbreed.val();
             objbreed.html(result.breed_opts);
             if(oldbreedid) {
                objbreed.val(oldbreedid);
             }
        }, "json" );
    });
</script>
```

After renewing html of select.breed, we restore the previously selected value, ie, that of step 2.